# Theoretical foundation of the moveit_msgs::Constraints constructGoalConstraints function

Tags: moveit, motion-planning

I'm new to MoveIt and motion planning.

I’m curious about the implementation of `constructGoalConstraints` function and check its source code

```
moveit_msgs::Constraints constructGoalConstraints(const std::string& link_name, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& pose,
                                                  const std::vector<double>& tolerance_pos,
                                                  const std::vector<double>& tolerance_angle)
{
  moveit_msgs::Constraints goal = constructGoalConstraints(link_name, pose);
  if (tolerance_pos.size() == 3)
  {
    shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive& bv = goal.position_constraints[0].constraint_region.primitives[0];
    bv.type = shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive::BOX;
    bv.dimensions.resize(geometric_shapes::solidPrimitiveDimCount<shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive::BOX>());
    bv.dimensions[shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive::BOX_X] = tolerance_pos[0];
    bv.dimensions[shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive::BOX_Y] = tolerance_pos[1];
    bv.dimensions[shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive::BOX_Z] = tolerance_pos[2];
  }
  if (tolerance_angle.size() == 3)
  {
    moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint& ocm = goal.orientation_constraints[0];
    ocm.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = tolerance_angle[0];
    ocm.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = tolerance_angle[1];
    ocm.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = tolerance_angle[2];
  }
  return goal;
}
```

Currently, I have no idea what is the theory behind this code snippet.

Could you give me a hint about some articles or books which describe a similar theory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Constraint is used to guide path planning. The MotionPlanRequest messsage lets you define two types of constraints: `path_constraints` and `goal_constraints`. Goal constraints let you define one or more conditions that must be met for the planner to decide that it has successfully reached the goal.

The most commonly used constraints are position and orientation limits for a link, but there are additional kinds of constraints. This ros1 web page has a more detailed explanation of the idea (search for the first instance of the word "constraint"):

https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/concepts/

The developers do not claim this is a universal system for defining every possible kind of Constraint. As far as I see, it has evolved piecemeal over time to include things that are useful for real-world conditions.

Comment: Hi! @Mike973 Thanks for your kind reply. I understand the role each constraint plays in planning. My confusion is whether there is a visual representation of the construction and representation of these constraint regions. Also, I would like to know if some articles have ever described these constraint regions. According to these codes, these regions are constructed in primitives and I think that some constraint regions cannot be expressed in primitives, what to do in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer. You probably need to modify the planner source code if you have a constraint that is not supported. I'm not aware of any tool to visualize constraints.